# How I can serialize vector in c++ to char for easy using mondodb for backend

Tags: c++, mongodb, serialization

I have `vector<matrix<float,o,1>> obj_id;`

matrix is:

```
class matrix : public matrix_exp<matrix<T,num_rows,num_cols, mem_manager,layout> >
```

I want to write  each item to the mongodb. I couldn find a solution for conversion.

But I can serialize  each item to write mongodb. But most of the serialization to file ofcourse.

How can I serialize to a char or any conveinient variable to insert mongodb as binary?

Best

Comment: How did you try to do it, and why did it fail?

Comment: I am a scala / java person.  using c++ most of the time things looks very different. I searched an example or a direction and couldnt find one . any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: it has been a while since I've been working in the C++ space, but a vector is in essence an array and you can use the BSON Document Builder examples on the MongoDB site for the Cxx driver to traverse over the array and construct the document:

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/working-with-bson/

To get the array-like access to the vector:

```cpp
if(obj_id.size()) {
    // create the pointer to the array
    double *myarray = &obj_id[0];

    // create a bson array builder and populate
    auto array_builder = bsoncxx::builder::basic::array{};

    for (const auto& element : elements) {
        array_builder.append(element);
    }

    // Add the array_builder result into a document
    // and save into the database
    ...
}
```

Again, my C++ is a bit rusty and my experience with the MongoDB Cxx driver is even more limited, but I hope that you have a sufficient pointer/start to continue your work.

Comment: Definitely I will try. thanks for your kind help and time